# What are real life use case of algorithms like median of median or selection algorithms (assuming unsorted array)?

Tags: algorithms

I am struggling to find out any real life (software) use case of using median of median or K’th Smallest/Largest Element in Unsorted Array problem.I found below text in link (https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2476272).

> However, partial sort (for which finding the median is a sub problem)
>   is an easy optimization relevant for search engines, where you
>   sometimes only need to extract the hits from position 1000-2000.

Apart from that, I am clueless why such problem exists in computer science and Interviews.

Your help is appreciated and will motivate me to understand computer science in a more realistic way.